# Firewall software with ip translation capability

Tags: networking, proxy, firewall, nat

I'm running a local socks proxy on my Windows machine. I have some ip adresses which can be reached only through this proxy because actually it is an ssh tunnel set up via putty. I thought maybe a firewall software with NAT settings could tunnel every request toward those ips through the proxy but I haven't find one yet. Since I would not use other capabilites of the firewall a lightweight one would fit the best. Although I have a tp-link archer c7 router I do not see NAT configuration option in it. Could you suggest a solution for this problem?

Comment: Questions seeking software recommendations are out of scope at SuperUser

Comment: I found proxifier, proxycap, widecap, sockscap can do the job.

Answer (score 1):

Even with the native firmware, the Archer C7 runs Linux, so has full Linux kernel firewall and IP-rewriting capabilities. These are just not exposed in the UI. However, you can install [OpenWRT](https://openwrt.org/toh/tp-link/archer-c7-1750) (or other open firmware derived from OpenWRT) on the router to be able to access these capabilities.

So you can either set it up to route back those requests to your Windows machine with the socks proxy, or you could run the socks proxy on the router in the first place.

Note you'll need to do a bit of reading how to configure all this, and you'll have to get familiar with the Linux command-line, though possible derived firmware (like DD-WRT) may have some UI ways to set this up (but I have no idea if they are complete).

I can't give any Windows software recommendations.